# Is doing something for people's reaction haram?

Tags: halal-haram

I actually got new glasses and i am actually gonna wear it to my class tomorrow and i want to see how people will react but is this haram? Like after going i have to wear it to see, so if i wear it while entering to see people's reaction haram? If it is, how should I wear because I just think I may for some reason do showoff, should I just let them see it or should I go to them and say I got glasses but I think I might showoff?

Answer (score 1):

The showing off that is haram is when someone pretends he is better than other people or when he does acts of worship supposed to be for Allah for the sake of other people seeing.

Example of the first: Someone wears fancy clothes because he thinks other people are less than him.

Example of the second: Someone prays a prayer because he wants to make someone else think he is pious.

Showing people other things is not Haram. This situation you have mentioned has no element of Haram in sight.